# Zeros of a sum of powers

Tags: polynomials, roots

Suppose we have a function of the form

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{k}Q_nx^{r_n}$$

where $0<r_n<1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^kQ_n=0$ (more on actually choosing these at the end of the question). Then $f(0)=f(1)=0$. My question is, is there a way to characterize (or provide a condition for) the number of zeros this $f(x)$ has on $(0,1)$? For example, for most functions we get this type of behavior

[image: No Zeros]

This comes from

$$f(x)=-\frac{59 x^{917/1000}}{250}+\frac{397 x^{841/1000}}{1000}+\frac{241 x^{299/500}}{1000}-\frac{281 x^{419/1000}}{1000}-\frac{121 x^{139/500}}{1000}$$

That is, no zeros on the interval. By most, I mean I ran some tests, and got that around $70\%$ had no zeros. Around $30\%$ had one zero, and a negligible amount had two zeros. For example

[image: Two Zeros]

which comes from

$$f(x)=\frac{59 x^{917/1000}}{250}-\frac{51 x^{841/1000}}{200}-\frac{141 x^{299/500}}{1000}+\frac{281 x^{419/1000}}{1000}-\frac{121 x^{139/500}}{1000}$$

has two zeros on the interval. I have no reason too believe that it is impossible to get even more zeros, but I have yet to find an example. Restating my question in a slightly different form, is there a way or method of choosing $Q_n$ and $r_n$ such that $f(x)$ has no zeros? Or is there a condition which guarantees this?

Comment: Would you like examples for $k=5$ in particular?

Comment: No, I'm looking at the general case of any $k>1$. I used $k=5$ because with more terms, I was able to produce more zeros. But I'll take anything for any $k$

Comment: I think there must be an error in the second graph you included in the question, because functions of your form must satisfy $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, and in the second picture, $f(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: It does equal zero, but Mathematica even with MaxRecursion has a hard time showing the behavior near zero. If you put it into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot(-(141%2F1000)+x%5E(598%2F1000)+%2B+(236%2F1000)+x%5E(917%2F1000)+%2B+(281%2F+++++1000)+x%5E(419%2F1000)+-+(121%2F+++++1000)+x%5E(278%2F1000)+-+(-141+%2B+236+%2B+281+-+121)%2F1000+x%5E(841%2F1000),%7Bx,0,1%7D)), looks even worse.

Comment: If it's that far off the mark at $x=0$, maybe you can't even trust the graph to count the number of zeros in $(0,1)$? idk

Comment: That could very well be true. The zeros can be hard to see. Here is an [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot((141%2F1000)+x%5E(598%2F1000)+%2B+(236%2F1000)+x%5E(917%2F1000)+%2B+(281%2F+++++1000)+x%5E(419%2F1000)+-+(121%2F+++++1000)+x%5E(278%2F1000)+-+(141+%2B+236+%2B+281+-+121)%2F1000+x%5E(841%2F1000),x,0,1)) with a zero near zero which is almost impossible to see in the graph.

Comment: Assume $r_n$ is ordered in ascending order. 
By Laguerre's generalization of Descartes' rule of signs, the number of 
positive roots (counting multiplicity) is at most (and has same parity) the number of sign changes in $Q_n$. This means in the special case that $Q_n$ has only one sign changes, $f(x)$ has exactly one positive root. Since $x = 1$ is a root, $f(x)$ has no other root in $(0,1)$.

Comment: By the way the functions you're summing are not called exponentials, but powers. So, your title should read, *Zeroes of a sum of powers,* and the wrong tag, too.

Comment: As for your question, note that *if $f''(x)$ is constant, then it will have no zeroes in $(0,1).$* Clearly this is far from a complete characterization, but is something to chew on in the meanwhile.